# Nested IF command with substrings in batch file fails

Tags: if-statement, cmd, syntax-error, substring

Okay so, I started to write a short batch file to check the individual length of the lines of the contents of a file, but in attempting to check if the line is equivalent to a substring of the itself (i.e. is it too long), this error occurs:

```
76Phrase] was unexpected at this time.
```

Here is what is being run:

```
IF EXIST file.ini (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%p IN (file.ini) DO (
        ...
        SET Phrase=%%p
        ...
        IF [%Phrase:~0,76%] EQU [%Phrase%] (
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried using ( ), " ", ' ', and nothing at all, as opposed to [ ], but it just throws out another error.

Am I doing something wrong? I haven't really used cmd in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion and the !variable! format if you are manipulating data inside a loop.

You may find this easier to check for long strings.

```
IF not "!Phrase:~76,1!"=="" echo too long
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have temporarily lost my sanity when I wrote my deleted comment.

Comment: I feel. SO STUPID. RGH.

Answer (score 1):

You need [delayed expansion](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) here, because `%` variables are expanded at parse-time, not at run-time.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

...

IF EXIST file.ini (
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%p IN (file.ini) DO (
    ...
    SET "Phrase=%%p"
    ...
    IF [!Phrase:~0,76!] EQU [!Phrase!] (
      ...
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Accepted the other guy's because you're a god among men already.